# See "Console SHUTDOWN event signaled" in Tomcat commons-daemon.log and Tomcat service stopped

Tags: tomcat, tomcat8

I'm facing an issue with Tomcat unexpected stopped. I saw the log entry in common-daemons.log showing an entry "Console SHUTDOWN event signaled" and then Tomcat service stopped.

I'm not quite familiar with Commons Daemon. May I ask for any insight what action can possible trigger this logging and then stop the services

Many thanks

```
[2019-04-22 00:13:49] [info]  [1344] Commons Daemon procrun (1.1.0.0 64-bit) started
[2019-04-22 00:13:49] [info]  [1344] Running 'Tomcat8' Service...
[2019-04-22 00:13:49] [info]  [5712] Starting service...
[2019-04-22 00:13:52] [info]  [5712] Service started in 3590 ms.
[2019-05-19 02:06:23] [info]  [4524] Console SHUTDOWN event signaled
[2019-05-19 02:06:23] [info]  [4524] Stopping service...
[2019-05-19 02:06:24] [info]  [4524] Service stop thread completed.
```

Comment: did you find solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

The messages in your log simply indicate that Tomcat was shutdown normally by the operating system.

To determine the cause you will need to look at the system logs from the time that Tomcat reports it was shut down.

I just experienced this on Windows and found the culprit in the System log (Event Viewer -> Windows Logs -> System). In our case, Tomcat was shut down each night for a Windows Update which was failing. About 2 minutes later Windows tried to restart Tomcat and failed due to the Windows service configuration. We had two things to fix.